# How to include images dynamically by names in React.js

Tags: reactjs, image, import, lang

I'm implementing language select and I need to add flags. I have tried Unicode emojis of flags but they didn't appear to work from React variables. Now I have downloaded png images of all the necessary flags.

I have an array of languages with name and value properties. Value property represents the locale code and name of the image file as well

```
languages: [
  {
    name: 'Swedish',
    value: 'sv_SE'
  },
  {
    name: 'English',
    value: 'en_US'
  },
  ...
]
```

I also have import statements:

```
import sv_SE from './flags/sv_SE.png'
import en_US from './flags/en_US.png'
```

and my `img` tag looks like this:

```
languages.map((lang) => (
   <img src={ sv_SE } alt={ lang.value }/>
)
```

It is showing the only Sweden flag for now. But I want to get the flag by array element value
Can you suggest any options I can use? Thank you for your patience!

Comment: You can use a template literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object that has each imageSource reference by the same key!

```
import sv_SE from './flags/sv_SE.png'
import en_US from './flags/en_US.png'

const flags = {
  sv_SE,
  en_US
}

...
languages.map((lang) => (
   <img src={ flags[lang.value] } alt={ lang.value }/>
)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You try this:

```
languages.map((lang) => (
   <img src={ `./flags/${lang.value}.png` } alt={ lang.value }/>
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! But it didn't work with relative path